# Does minimizer of sum of Hamming distances of subsets in a parititon and of sum of mean Hamming distances give the same result?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I have a set $U$ of binary vectors $u$ which are partitioned by a partition $P_a$ into two subsets $U_1,U_2$ s.t. the sum of Hamming distances of elements in each subset is minimal, i.e. $\sum_{i=1..2} H(U_i)$ is minimal, where $H(U) = \sum_{u,u' \in U} H(u,u')$.

Is the partition $P_m$ that minimizes the sum of mean Hamming distances of each subset the same, i.e. $P_m = \text{argmin}_{P}\sum_{i=1..2}H_m(\{u_j \in U | P_{j,i}=1\}) = P_a$, where $H_m(U_i) = 1/|U_i|^2 H(U_i)$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to provide a general proof, but below is also a counter example that shows its not true in general.

Assume $U_1,U_2$ satisfy $P_a$, then for all non empty partitions $U_3,U_4$ we have:
$$
H(U_3) + H(U_4) \geq H(U_2) + H(U_1)
$$

Now using $U_1,U_2$ we show that there exists a non empty partition $U_3,U_4$ that violates the condition $P_m$:
$$
\frac{1}{|U_3|^2}H(U_3) + \frac{1}{|U_4|^2}H(U_4) < \frac{1}{|U_2|^2}H(U_2) + \frac{1}{|U_1|^2}H(U_1) \leq H(U_2) + H(U_1)
$$
with condition $P_a$:

$$
\frac{1}{|U_3|^2}H(U_3) + \frac{1}{|U_4|^2}H(U_4) < H(U_3) + H(U_4)
$$

now chose the partition $U_3$ such that $|U_3|=1$:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{|U_4|^2}H(U_4) < 1 + H(U_4)
$$

which is true if $|U_4|\neq1$ or $|U|>2$. Therefore found a partition that is smaller in $P_m$ than $U_1,U_2$.

---

Counter example to show its not the same in general, might be tedious the calculate all possibilities by hand:

Let
$$ 
u_1=(1,0,1)\\
u_2=(1,1,1)\\
u_3=(0,0,0)\\
u_4=(1,1,0)\\\text{and }U = \{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\} $$

Then all non empty partitions of $P_a$ consist of 2 elements, e.g $U_1=\{u_1,u_2\}$, $U_2=\{u_3,u_4\}$:

$$
H(U_1) + H(U_2) = 2 + 4 =6
$$

One possible partiton satisfying $P_m$ is $U_3=\{u_1,u_2,u_4\}$, $U_4=\{u_3\}$:

$$
 H_m(U_1) + H_m(U_2) = \frac{6}{4} > H_m(U_3)+H_m(U_4) = \frac{2+4+2}{9}+\frac{0}{1}
$$

thus $P_a$ and $P_m$ generate different partitions.

Comment: Thanx. Small correction: H(U3) = 0 in the proof, but that doesn't change the result.